# Best way to track userinformation after login?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to understand best practises for storing login info after my user has been authenticated. Is it best to use page level propertys , session or what approch.

Ideally this is what I want to be able to perform on my login click im doing the following then on each page after i want to be able to do is

if (userValid and IsAuhtorised and Status =Admin)
then 
else do 404 i guess would be best approach.

Sorry I should have sateted not allowed to use ms built in systems.

```
       DBContext _db = new DBContext();


        UserValidationResult userStatus=_db.ValidateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        Session["level"] = userStatus.userLevel.ToString();
        Session["username"] = userStatus.User.username;
        Session["logedin"] = true;


        if (userStatus.Status == Mercentwarehousecms.User.UserValidationResult.LStatus.InvalidPassword)
        {
            lblFailed.Text = "Invlaid Password";
        }

        if (userStatus.Status == Mercentwarehousecms.User.UserValidationResult.LStatus.UserDoesNotExist)
        {

            lblFailed.Text = "User Does Not Exist";
        }

        if (userStatus.Status == Mercentwarehousecms.User.UserValidationResult.LStatus.Sucess && userStatus.userLevel == Mercentwarehousecms.User.UserValidationResult.UserLevel.Administrator)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/admin/users/default.aspx");


        }

        if (userStatus.userLevel == Mercentwarehousecms.User.UserValidationResult.UserLevel.StoreManager)
        {
            lblFailed.Text = "i AM store manager ";
        }
```

Comment: One way is to use Forms Authentication. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @RickS cant use built in ones this has to be custom mate

Comment: You really shouldn't differentiate between "Invalid Password" and "User Does Not Exist", at least not in the UI

Comment: @SteveCzetty its not for the ui mate just internal

Comment: Guys i didnt ask about the ode i just asked what is best way to store it at page level or else session and if session how

Comment: I don't see an issue with using `Session` to store information about the user.  You could create a `User` class (object) and store that in the Session.  Then you only have one Session object to set and retrieve.

Comment: I guess you already have a class called `userStatus`.  Maybe just store that in your Session instead of each property separately.

Comment: @Ricks would u provide a code example of that please and demostrate so i can mark urs as the answer thanks what about encryption though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change this:**

```
    UserValidationResult userStatus=_db.ValidateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    Session["level"] = userStatus.userLevel.ToString();
    Session["username"] = userStatus.User.username;
    Session["logedin"] = true;
```

**To:**

```
       UserValidationResult userStatus=_db.ValidateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
       Session["userStatus"] = userStatus;
```

Then later on you can retrieve it:

```
        UserValidationResult userStatus = (UserValidationResult)Session["userStatus"];
```

I don't know what you mean about encryption. Use SSL if you want to protect the user's password from going over the wire as clear text.

Comment: I have it encrypted using Rijndael think should be strong enough for the demo anyway